# Excel VBA use defined name for table name

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, range

In the following code, I am sorting my table named DepList on the DepName column.

```
    Sub SortDepNameAZ()
    On Error Resume Next
         ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Department List").ListObjects("DepList").Sort. _
             SortFields.Clear
         ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Department List").ListObjects("DepList").Sort. _
             SortFields.Add Key:=Range("DepList[[#All],[DepName]]"), SortOn:= _
             xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
         With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Department List").ListObjects("DepList").Sort
           .Header = xlYes
           .MatchCase = False
           .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
           .SortMethod = xlPinYin
           .Apply
        End With
     End Sub
```

I want to make this more general so I can use it as a function, using defined ranges and names instead of specific names.

I have tried using the following but I can't make the syntax work:

```
 Sub SortDepNamesAZ(lo1 As ListObject, dn1 as Variant)
 On Error Resume Next
     Set lo1 = Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ListObject(1)
     Dim tabstr As String
     tabstr = Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ListObject(1).Name
     lo1.Sort.SortFields.Clear
     lo1.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(tabstr[[#All],[dn1]]), SortOn:= _
         xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending 'I think this line is probably wrong??
     With lo1.Sort
         .Header = xlYes
         .MatchCase = False
         .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
         .SortMethod = xlPinYin
         .Apply
     End With
 End Sub
```

Any help appreciated, even if only a few pointers as I know the code could probably be improved on many levels.

Thanks

Comment: Two things... `1` Get rid of On Error Resume Next. Do proper error handling `2` Your Range `Range(tabstr[[#All],[dn1]])` is not fully qualified. How will the function know which sheet it refers to? | Once you have taken care of the above, test it again and tell which line is giving you the error and what error is it?

Comment: To clarify, do you want to pass a table reference/name and column name to the function and have the function sort the table by the column?

Comment: @DougGlancy yes, though it is my first time writing a function so I was not sure how to. I have written it like this and it seems to work:

Comment: That looks reasonable to me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function:

```
Sub SortTableByHeader(ShtN As String, tabN As String, hed1 As Variant) 
Dim hed2 As Range, hed3 As Integer 

Set hed2 = Range(tabN).Rows(0) 
    hed3 = Application.Match(hed1, hed2, 0) 

Range(tabN).Sort Key1:=Range(tabN).Cells(1, hed3), Header:=xlYes 

End Sub
```

Calling the function:

```
Sub SortDepartmentName() 
Dim ShtN As String, objName As String, myColHead As Variant 

ShtN = Sheets("Department List").Name 
objName = Sheets("Department List").ListObjects(1).Name 
myColHead = "DepName" 

SortTableByHeader ShtN, objName, myColHead 

End Sub
```